# Do I need to disclose '' REQUIRED TO LEAVE CHINA'' in my new UK application

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, applications

My Request to inlude my new born baby in my Chinese residency documents and by extension, visa extension was refused by Chinese authorities in Guangzhou China in 2007. According to them, I was supposed to report the birth of the child one month after birth by law. Consequently, my child was ordered to leave China within two weeks. However, since my child had no separate int'l passport, I was ordered to leave China with him as his mother. Do I need to disclose this in my UK skilled worker application form? Again, does UK share immigration information with China?

Comment: Please amend your question (using the "Edit" button below the question text) so that your question includes the exact wording of the question(s) in the UK Skilled Worker application form which you must answer.

Comment: I think it’s vanishingly unlikely that the UK routinely shares immigration data with China. Regardless of that however, you *must* answer all questions in the UK application truthfully. Failing to do so would be deception, which would have far worse consequences if discovered than telling the truth and explaining the circumstances.

Comment: @Traveller that sounds like an answer

Comment: Where are you now? Is your child going to accompany you to the UK?